# Mockito error on MediaType.multipart

Tags: java, mockito

We have a service which take input as MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE sample as below.

API as below

```
   public class Request{
        private String id;
        private String fileName;
        private MultipartFile multipartFile;
        //getter setters
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadTemplate", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadTemplate(@ModelAttribute("testFile") Request inputParam,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws IOException {   
           uploadservice.uploadFile(inputParam.getMultipartFile(),  inputParam.getFileName());

           return new ResponseEntity<>("file uploaded ", headers, HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
            }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_uploadTemplate_200() throws IOException, AWSException {
        private MockMvc mockMvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(templateController).setHandlerExceptionResolvers(exceptionResolver)
            .build();;
        private MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("files", "FileUploadTest.txt", "text/plain", "This is a Test".getBytes());
        when(uploadservice.uploadFile(mockMultipartFile, "MyFile.xlsx")).thenReturn("Success");

        try {
          this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/v1/1222/fileUpload/uploadFile")
              .file(mockMultipartFile).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful()).andDo(print());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Assert.fail("Exception occured: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Error reported by above test java.lang.AssertionError:

> Exception occured: Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type
>   [org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest]:
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartHttpServletRequest@181d8899

Is this not correct way to mock multipart using mockito.

Thanks, Anjana

Comment: Looks like your code snippets are not consistent. I tried to format the post, but is not clear to me if there is a separation from the class _Request_ and the tests.

Comment: Thanks accepted your changes

Comment: I think you need to Extend your request using MockMultipartHttpServletRequest, which is not clear if you are doing.

Comment: No . Can you please provide example of extending using MockMultipartHttpServletRequest